# Novel about astronauts visiting a planet with primitive life. The Natives are humanoid with long arms

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I read this book when I was a boy (85-89)but it wasn't a children's book. It had a blue sky and a tree on the cover. An astronaut was reaching up to an Alien in the tree. Written in English. It was hardcover but shorter and smaller than a normal hardcover novel.

The opening chapters deal with the discovery of an Earth-like planet. A team of explorers is sent to investigate and they discover a race of humanoid aliens.

My biggest takeaway from this novel was that the aliens have elongated arms. I also think they may have lived in trees.

Comment: And... **When** where you a boy? We don't know that :) please [edit] the information in your answer, as well as anything else you could remember, such as the cover, the language it was published in, etc, etc